# flex: Drag and drop of copy- image instantiation in AS

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

I am working on a flex project

I am building drag-and-drop functionality in AS. I have a situation where I need to pick image items from the left and drop it onto a grid. Three specific requirements
a) some conditions around alignment
b) I want a copy of the image to be dropped- not the original
c) the dropped image needs to be movable again

while I know how to create a drag-droppable object in mxml using

```
<mx:Image id="img" x="100" y="100" source="img.png" mouseMove="mouseMoveHandler(event);"/>
```

how do I do a equivalent where I need to achieve (c). My current approach is to achieve (b) do as follows- Create a new image

```
var newImage:Image=new Image();
newImage.id="Element"+String(count); //increment count to create newer objects
newImage.source = draggedImage.source;
 //conditions to do alignment
```

How do I do equivalent of newimage.mouseMove as in the mxml above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post feels a bit scattered; so I believe this is the only question:

> How do I do equivalent of
>   newimage.mouseMove as in the mxml
>   above

The MXML version, from your sample is like this:

```
<mx:Image id="img" mouseMove="mouseMoveHandler(event);"/>
```

In ActionScript, you would do something like this:

```
img.AddEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoveHandler);
```